# Empty ViewModel returned from view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 for a website, and one of the things I'm making is a CSV import. I want to map the CSV columns onto properties of the ORM. After the file is uploaded, I want to display the column number, the first line (containing the header in the csv file) and the second line (data preview).

```
/// <summary>
/// The mapping view model.
/// </summary>
public class MappingViewModel
{
    #region Public Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the mappings.
    /// </summary>
    public IList<Mapping> Mappings { get; set; }

    public MappingViewModel()
    {
        //this.Mappings = new List<Mapping>();
    }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
/// The mapping.
/// </summary>
public class Mapping
{
    #region Public Properties

    public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }

    public string ColumnHeader { get; set; }

    public string DataPreview { get; set; }

    public string PropertyIdentifier { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

I've created a strongly typed Razor view where I loop through the list inside the model as follows:

```
@model MappingViewModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("ApplyMapping", "Person"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(t=>t.FileName)
    <table class="i-table fullwidth">
        <thead>
...table header
        </thead>
        @foreach (var mapping in Model.Mappings)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(x=>mapping.ColumnIndex)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => mapping.ColumnHeader)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => mapping.DataPreview)</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>mapping.PropertyIdentifier,(SelectList)ViewBag.PropertyList)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="@Resources.Default.ButtonSaveText" class="icon16-button forms-16" />
}
```

And that's not working for me. The data is displayed, but the receiving controller action gets an empty model - with the exception of the filename.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Action is as follows:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadAdvanced(FormCollection collection)
        {
 // csv stuff + get property list

            var viewModel = new MappingViewModel();
            viewModel.Mappings = new List<Mapping>();
            for (int i = 0; i < headers.Count(); i++)
            {
                viewModel.Mappings.Add(new Mapping() { ColumnIndex = i, DataPreview = firsLine[i], ColumnHeader = headers[i],PropertyIdentifier = string.Empty });
            }
            viewModel.FileName = file.FileName;
            var propertyList = new SelectList(propList);
            this.ViewBag.PropertyList = propertyList;
            return this.View("Mapping", viewModel);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ApplyMapping(MappingViewModel model)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(model.ToString());

            return this.View("Index");
        }
```

I'm reading the viewmodel props from a breakpoint in the ApplyMapping actionResult. When the breakpoint hits - filename is set correctly, the list is NULL

Comment: Hi Jorge, thanks - they are inside the form and I changed them to EditFor but that dit not change anything. Still the filename comes back from the view, but the list is returning null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's empty probably because all the properties are using a `DisplayFor` instead of `EditorFor` second they need to be inside of the BeginForm, if you Could you shows us the action?

**UPDATE**

Change the datatype from IList to IEnumerable, second initialize the attribute in the constructor.

```
/// <summary>
/// The mapping view model.
/// </summary>
public class MappingViewModel
{
    #region Public Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the mappings.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<Mapping> Mappings { get; set; }

    public MappingViewModel()
    {
        //this.Mappings = new List<Mapping>();
        IEnumerable<Mapping> test = new HashSet<Mapping>();
    }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Created a EditorTemplate in this path (/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/) for your class Mapping with the format that you need for example

```
@model SomePath.Models.Mapping 

<tr> 
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ColumnIndex)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ColumnHeader)</td>
</tr>
```

Then Remove the for in the View for the property Mapping and usee the `EditorFor` Helper like this

```
@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Mappings)
```

That should the problem of serialize the attribute

Comment: Hi Jorge, thanks - they are inside the form and I changed them to EditFor but that dit not change anything. Still the filename comes back from the view, but the list is returning null

Comment: Show me the action to see what's happen also, update you're question with the changes in the view

Comment: Thanks, done. Could it have to do with serializability of the list?

Comment: @user896697 Still having troubles?

Comment: Hi Jorge - yes I applied the changes but that did not do the trick. The Mappings property is not NULL anymore, but a set with length 0.

Comment: @spike let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13324/discussion-between-jorge-and-spike)

Comment: Thanks Jorge - creating an editorTemplate for the Mapping object resulted in a non-empty list in the controller. Thanks!